# Scroll slider in android?

Tags: android

I am new to android.I made string array.It has more elements starts with A to Z . I make list View for the array.When i scroll the screen i wish to display the starting letter.If i remove the hand at the letter 's' then i will display the items starts with the letter 's'

as like the following link

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rcPIvGRwrxA

Answer (score 2):

You will want to [use `android:fastScrollEnabled="true"` on a `ListView`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607132/contact-app-like-scrollinglist-on-android) for that.