# Android accelerated scroll "first letter"

Tags: android, scroll, letter

How can I use "first-letter" feature when user performs accelerated scrolling?
See the [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rcPIvGRwrxA) @ 0:20

Comment: possible duplicate of [Contact-app like scrollinglist on android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607132/contact-app-like-scrollinglist-on-android)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Short: `setFastScrollEnabled(true);` on the ListView

Or take a look at a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122749/create-easy-alphabetical-scrolling-in-listview/5122846)

Comment: I need to show the first letter popup. I know how to enable the accelerated scroller